# Как удалить значения между слэш "/"

Tags: php, str-replace

Есть строки:

```
/download/doc/bd2/bd217ce34263e9bf8679562067758196.xls|/download/doc/17f/17fc9e435a3d3a1d1e6f12c13fe1262f.xls|/download/doc/42b/42be09853a529555d6f2316f1f29b593.xls
```

Нужно чтобы получилось:

```
bd217ce34263e9bf8679562067758196.xls|17fc9e435a3d3a1d1e6f12c13fe1262f.xls|42be09853a529555d6f2316f1f29b593.xls
```

Функцией `str_replace` не получается, т.к. после 3 слэша параметры все время меняются.

Пробовала функцию `strrchr`

```
$param = "/download/doc/bd2/bd217ce34263e9bf8679562067758196.xls|/download/doc/17f/17fc9e435a3d3a1d1e6f12c13fe1262f.xls|/download/doc/42b/42be09853a529555d6f2316f1f29b593.xls
";
$string = substr(strrchr($param, "/"), 1);
echo $string;
```

Но она возвращает только `42be09853a529555d6f2316f1f29b593.xls`

Comment: Разбить строку по '|' и использовать [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например,так

```
$result = preg_replace('~/[\w/]*/~', "", $str);
```

либо так

```
$result = [];
foreach(explode('|', $str) as $file){
    $result[] = basename($file);
}
$str = implode("|", $result);
```

что можно записать как

```
$str = implode("|", array_map('basename', explode("|", $str)));
```

Comment: @ЮляФролова подходит, пока в вырезаемом пути только буквы, цифры и `/`. Возможно придется расширять набор `[\w/]` другими символами. И вопрос по эффективности на входной строке большой длины.

Comment: @ЮляФролова,  если teran ответил на ваш вопрос, поставьте галочку слева от ответа, чтобы отметить его как верный